# Extending forecast model to ADL and comparing with VAR

Tags: regression, stata, vector-autoregression

I'm currently working on bond return data. I've data for 5,10,20 and 30 years. I've performed PCA, EFA. I also created an AR(11) model to forecast the return for the next month that's due. Now I want to extend my model to ADL with $X_{t-1}$ as a covariate. Here, Xt-1 is the lag of the first principal component from a PCA performed on the returns of the bonds with maturities aforementioned maturities. I need help in assessing whether the inclusion of Xt-1 improves my forecasts. If possible,help in connecting this ADL model with a vector autoregressive model (VAR) of order 1. For starters, I saved the first principal component as a new variable (pc1) using the following Stata-commands (assuming the whole sample is used).

```
pca cov1 cov2 cov3 cov4
predict pc1, score
```